# Not getting json when using .text in bs4

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In this code I think I made a mistake or something because I'm not getting the correct `json` when I print it, indeed I get nothing but when I index the script I get the `json` but using `.text` nothing appears I want the `json` alone.

CODE :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
import requests
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

base_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/{}'

search = input('Enter the instagram account: ')

final_url = base_url.format(quote_plus(search))

response = requests.get(final_url)

print(response.status_code)
if response.ok:
    html = response.text
    bs_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
    scripts = bs_html.select('script[type="application/ld+json"]')
    print(scripts[0].text)
```

Comment: What search string did you use? I slightly tweaked your code in my [repl code](https://repl.it/@DamodarDahal/WarpedCloudySlash), but it works when input `"abcd"`.

Comment: it does not giv a script right?

Comment: It does if `search = "abcd"`, which is a public page. It does not work if `search="damodar.dahal"`, which is my private instagram account.

Comment: i see, it dint work fr me in python. can u chek if there is some error in my code, not the modified one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line `print(scripts[0].text)` to `print(scripts[0].string)`.

`scripts[0]` is a Beautiful Soup `Tag` object, and its string contents can be accessed through the `.string` property.

Source: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string

If you want to then turn the string into a json so that you can access the data, you can do something like this:

```
...

if response.ok:
    html = response.text
    bs_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
    scripts = bs_html.select('script[type="application/ld+json"]')
    json_output = json.loads(scripts[0].string)
```

Then, for example, if you run `print(json_output['name'])` you should be able to access the name on the account.

Comment: yup it does the job,but can u please tell me how to load this into json, if you know?

Comment: Are you trying to save it as a json file?

Comment: the same code, but im trying this ```html = response.text
    bs_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
    scripts = bs_html.select('script[type="text/javascript"]')
    data = scripts[3].string
    jso = json.loads(data)
    print(jso)```

Comment: that is im trying to use `loads` and trying to print tht out, so i can access the data inside?

Comment: `scripts[3]` won't work because `scripts` only has one element. See the edited response :)

Comment: all i fine, but i changed the script type to text/javascrip and tried to 3rd element but it gives ```raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)``` Thanks for help so far :)